# Why is the number of subsets in a sample space $2^n$?

Tags: self-study, combinatorics, subset, set-theory

I am working my way through the statistical inference textbook and am stuck on this question:

- Suppose that a sample space $S$ has $n$ elements. Prove that the
  number of subsets that can be formed from the elements of S is $2^n$

Taking examples for $n=2$:
$$n=2;\{\{\emptyset \}, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a,b\}\};$$
And for $n=3$
$$n=3;\{\{\emptyset \}, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, \{b,c\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$$

I do understand that any subset needs to be constructed by including and excluding elements of $n$ but I am not sure how to prove it. Just showing a few examples seems to not be enough.

What would be a formal proof of this simple fact?

Comment: Hint: for each subset of S, each one of the $n$ elements of S is either in this subset or not. This means that there $n$ binary decisions to make. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Use induction on $n.$ Given a set $S$ of cardinality $n+1,$ pick one element $x$ in it and partition its subsets into those that include $x$ and those that don't. Each member of that partition is in one-to-one correspondence with $S\setminus\{x\}.$

Comment: I wonder if this is on topic; see, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3582854/220145)

Comment: @utobi IMO this is borderline. Yes, there is strictly no statistical concept in it, but certainly it is _related_. I am seeing it as a self-study question probably on any elementary probability exercises for which OP has shown their efforts.

Comment: One mathematical definition of $2^n$ is that it's the cardinality of the set of functions from $n$ to $2,$ written $[2]^{[n]},$ where (again by definition) $[n] = \{0,1,\ldots, n-1\}$ and $[2]=\{0,1\}.$ Define a map from $\mathscr P(S)$ (the power set of $S$) and $[2]^{[n]}$ sending any subset $X\subset S$ to its indicator function. This map is obviously invertible, whence (by the definition of cardinality) $\mathscr P(S)$ has $2^n$ elements. This construction extends to infinite cardinals $n:$ the cardinal $2^n$ is the cardinality of the power set of any set of cardinality $n.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the comments, so I tried to answer it myself.

Each element of $S$ can either be in the subet or not. For each elements we only have two options, all the subsets will therefore be represented by the multiplications of all the choices.

With the logic taken care of, here's the proof.

Proof by induction:

1. Prove the base case:

   $n=2$; possible subsets: $\{\{\emptyset\}, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a,b\}\}$

   $2.2=2^2=4$
2. Assume that it's true for $k$:

   $n=k$; possible subsets: $\{\{\emptyset\}, \{a\}, \{b\},..., \{a,b,....,k\}\}$

   $2...2=2^k$
3. Show that it's true for $k+1$:

   $n=k+1$; possible subsets: $\{\{\emptyset\}, \{a\}, \{b\},..., \{a,b,....,k,k+1\}\}$

   $2...2=2^k.2=2^{k+1}$

Which should be enough to prove the fact.

Comment: If this was homework I would not give such an answer full credit, the way you have listed out hte possible subsets for the $k+1$ case does not indicate in any way why the total possible is $2*2^k$. It is much clearer if you say the possible subsets for $k+1$ case are $\{\{\emptyset\}, \{k+1\}, \{a\},\{a,k+1\}, \{b\},\{b,k+1\}, \ldots, \{a,b,\ldots,k\}, \{a,b,\ldots,k,k+1\}\}$ where you have all of the possible subsets from the $k$ case plus all of those sets with $k+1$ you therefore have double the number of subsets, ie $2*2^k = 2^{k+1}$

Comment: Also, your demonstration is incomplete: the base case is $n=0,$ not $n=2.$

Answer (score 4):

**You ask for a formal proof.**  That requires definitions and a simple construction.  *I offer these because they are generally useful in statistics.*

The following is merely a formal way of explaining that any binary vector determines a subset (from the positions of its $1$s) and, conversely, any set of positions determines a binary vector.

---

**First, the construction, because it's the crux of the matter.**  When $S$ is a set and $A\subseteq S,$ the *indicator function* $\mathscr I_{A;S}$ is the relation

$$ \mathscr I_{A;S} = \{(x,0)\mid x\in S,\ x \notin A\} \cup \{(x,1)\mid x \in A\}.$$

The set of all indicator functions with domain $S$ doesn't have any conventional name, so here let's call it $\mathcal{I}(S).$  Because a function on any set $S$ is a *vector,* **you can think intuitively of $\mathcal I(S)$ as the set of binary vectors indexed by $S.$**

As a matter of notation, for any set $S$, write $|S|$ for its cardinality. (All you need to know about cardinality is that two sets $S$ and $T$ have the same cardinality if and only if there exist injective functions from $S$ to $T$ and from $T$ to $S.$)

1. The definition of powers of $2$ is $|\mathcal{I}(S)| = 2^{|S|}.$  That is, when $n$ is any cardinal, $2^n$ is the cardinality of the set of indicator functions on any set $S$ of cardinality $n.$  (Intuitively, $2^n$ counts how many binary numbers with $n$ digits there are -- even when $n$ is zero or infinite!)
2. It is an axiom of set theory that the collection of all subsets of any set $S$ -- its "power set" $\mathscr P(S)$  -- is a set.

**The question asks to show that $\mathcal{I}(S)$ and $\mathscr P(S)$ have the same cardinality for any finite set $S.$**  We won't require finiteness in this proof.

1. Let $\sigma: \mathscr{P}(S) \to \mathcal I(S)$ map any subset of $S$ to its indicator function.
2. Let $\tau: \mathcal I(S) \to \mathscr P(S)$ assign to any indicator function $\mathscr I$ the set $\{x\in S\mid \mathscr I(x)=1\}.$  That is, *the $1$'s in a binary vector determine a subset.*

It is immediate (from the initial construction and definitions) that the compositions $\sigma\circ \tau$ and $\tau\circ\sigma$ are the identity functions on $\mathcal I(S)$ and $\mathscr P(S),$ respectively.  Therefore both $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are bijective, whence $|\mathcal I(S)| = |\mathscr P(S)|,$ *QED.*

In statistical parlance, certain subsets $A$ of a probability space $S$ are *events* while their indicator functions $\mathscr I_{A;S}$ are *random variables.*  This demonstration, as embodied in the maps $\sigma$ and $\tau,$ shows how we can freely move back and forth between the two concepts as needed.

---

In light of other attempts in this thread to display proofs that do not rely (explicitly) on induction, notice that use of mathematical induction cannot possibly be lurking, because such a result would apply at best to ordinal numbers, not all cardinals.

Comment: This is the only proof here that actually avoids induction (+1).  As with some other proposed proofs on this site (see e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/608561/608592#608592) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/397122/397200#397200)), the other methods introduce question-begging elements by using premises/rules that are arguably *consequences* of the theorem rather than genuine preliminaries.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two combinatorial non-inductive proofs.

Suppose $S = \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$, where $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ are distinct.  The goal is to count the number of all the subsets of $S$.  In other words, to count the number of ways of constructing a subset of $S$.

*Proof 1 (Apply the [Rule of Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_principles#Rule_of_sum) principle)*.  This is based on the observation that a subset of $S$ can contain $i$ elements ($0 \leq i \leq n$), which are mutually exclusive. The number of subsets that contain $i$ elements is $\binom{n}{i}$, which is the number of ways of choosing $i$ elements from a pool of $n$ elements.    Therefore, by the rule of sum principle, the number of distinct subsets is given by:
\begin{align}
\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \cdots + \binom{n}{n} = 2^n,
\end{align}
by Newton's binomial identity.

*Proof 2 (Apply the [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_principles#Rule_of_product) principle)*.  This is based on the observation that constructing a subset is equivalent to assigning a binary label "on/off" to each of $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ such that a subset contains elements that are assigned with the "on" label.  Therefore, the number of subsets is equal to the number of ways of forming an $n$-long "on-off" sequence. As each element can either be "on" or "off" (i.e., $2$ ways of labeling one element) and there are $n$ elements in total, by the rule of product principle, there are
\begin{align}
\underbrace{2 \times 2 \times \cdots \times 2}_{n \text{ times}} = 2^n
\end{align}
ways of forming an $n$-long "on-off" sequence, i.e., there are $2^n$ subsets in total.

Comment: Both these demonstrations merely disguise the (usual) inductive demonstrations of the facts you rely on.  Any truly non-inductive demonstration would (non-inductively!) establish a bijection between $\mathscr P(S)$ (the power set) and $2^S$ (the maps from $S$ to $\{0,1\}$).